# get deleted contacts returns null sometimes

Tags: android, contacts

I need to retrieve deleted contacts in android. Below is my code

```
String WHERE_MODIFIED = "( "+ ContactsContract.RawContacts.DELETED + "= 1 )";

Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI,
        null,
        WHERE_MODIFIED,
        null,
        null);
if (c.getCount() > 0) {
  c.moveToFirst();
  do{
      String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
      Log.e(TAG,name);
  }while (c.moveToNext());
}else {
    Log.e(TAG,"cursor = null");
}
```

It works when I delete contact and fetch using above code but after sometime of deletion it returns null. How do I fix this?

Comment: there is not a single `return` statement in this code...

Comment: my question is why this query returns null after sometime ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Cursor cursor = createDeletedCursor(contactLastUpdatedTime); 


private Cursor createDeletedCursor(long lastupdatedTime) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
        return resolver.query(
                ContactsContract.DeletedContacts.CONTENT_URI,
                DELETED_PROJECTION,
                String.format("%s >= %d", ContactsContract.DeletedContacts.CONTACT_DELETED_TIMESTAMP, lastupdatedTime),
                null,
                ContactsContract.DeletedContacts.CONTACT_ID
        );
}
```